# Как получить текст страницы, а не exception?

Tags: java, http, httpclient

Добрый день.
Хочу получить данные с сайта, для этого использую Apache HttpComponents.
Запрос такой:

```
public Header[] sendRequest() throws IOException {
    CloseableHttpResponse responsePost = null;
    HttpPost httpPost;
    httpPost = new HttpPost(urlForRequest);
    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, "UTF-8"));
    responsePost = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    HttpEntity entityPost = responsePost.getEntity();
    sourceTextFile = EntityUtils.toString(entityPost);
    responsePost.close();
    return responsePost.getHeaders("Location");
}
```

При запросе текста страницы вылетает исключение

```
15:39:20,061 ERROR [stderr] java.nio.charset.IllegalCharsetNameException: America/New_York

Заголовок ответа содержит ошибочные данные
Connection  : close
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 20
Content-Type: text/html; charset=America/New_York
Date    : Thu, 13 Oct 2016 12:41:28 GMT
```

Content-Type отдаваемы сайтом равен text/html; charset=America/New_York.
Из-за этого на строке

```
sourceTextFile = EntityUtils.toString(entityPost);
```

получаю exception.

Как при получении неправильного заголовка ContentType прочитать содержимое страницы в файл ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ошибка возникает потому что метод `EntityUtils.toString()` при чтении entity использует кодировку из заголовка http ответа и выкидывает `java.nio.charset.IllegalCharsetNameException`, так как `America/New_York` не является валидной кодировкой (и вообще кодировкой).
Чтобы обойти эту ошибку, можно считать тело ответа как поток используя `entityPost.getContent()`.

Comment: Спасибо, так и сделал. Все варианты получения текста через getContent() нашел здесьhttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/309424/read-convert-an-inputstream-to-a-string